# Select rendered LaTex from Wikipedia with Chrome?

Tags: support, mathjax

As someone who often copy and paste from Wikipedia, I have this particular question with Chrome.

In Firefox, if I select and copy the rendered LaTex in Wikipedia,  then what I get is LaTex code. But in Chrome, I can copy nothing. I wonder how to make it work in Chrome similarly to Firefox? For example, [the formula used for defining the support of a Borel measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28measure_theory%29#Definition). Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the *X* is capitalized in *LaTeX*.

Comment: You can always click on edit and copy the LaTeX code from the source of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Now it should be also possible to use MathJax to render formulas on wikipedia, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Using_MathJax). (Here is [link to the current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Help:Displaying_a_formula&oldid=638909209#Using_MathJax).)

Comment: Now I'm confused, why was this asked here?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I can imagine that somebody wants to ask about some result they saw on Wikipedia. It is easier and more efficient to copy a complicated formula than to type it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is probably not the right or best way of doing it, but if you right click on the image of the formula in Chrome and choose "Inspect element", the code for the page comes up with the line where the image occurs highlighted. The LaTeX for the formula is provided there. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Double-clicking on the line lets you select and copy the LaTeX:

[image]

Comment: Now it should also be possible to use select and image and copy it as a latex formula on Wikipedia on Chrome. See Sleziak's comments.